# Start a Holding Company?

Tags: investing, small-business, business

I'm 23 I've recently graduated college with two bachelor's degrees and have studied finance extensively in my spare time. I work as a software engineer, and even though I don't hate the work I know it's not what I want to do long-term (it does pay the bills for now though).

I love saving, I love investing, and I love managing money. I've always wanted to start a business but recently I've decided I may be best suited as an investor, I feel this is my true passion.

I want a company that will own other companies (I would start this by owning my 3 personal companies) with hopes of expanding to buy larger and larger companies, all the while holding investments in debt and equities.

Is it plausible to think I can start a company that owns other companies but has the held companies actually run by someone else (management teams)? Am I off track here? Would I just manage the money and ensure all held companies are on track and doing well and find stocks to produce income? Would I have unforeseen responsibilities I haven't considered? How should I structure this? How much capital will I need (I know this varies, but I want to start pretty small)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't feel it is about personal finance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to invest in closely held / private companies (things that don't trade on the stock market), you will run into a variety of regulatory problems.

For various reasons, most private companies only raise funds with accredited investors. To be an accredited investor you basically have to have $1,000,000 in net worth - NOT including your primary residence, OR you have to make over $200,000 a year for the last two years and expect to keep making that much. This is a class distinction the Federal government created, you will see different but similar wealth and investment classes worldwide.

So your best most organized opportunities are left out, unless you do qualify as an accredited investor.

There are tons of other companies, things you will find locally, that will let you invest in their smaller time operations. (Think like a local yoga studio looking for $20,000 and willing to split the profits with you). But the problem here is lack of accountability, where partners skip town or just stop answering your calls, and the legal remedies cost you more than your claim.

That being said there are people that provide capital to smaller publicly traded companies on the bulletin boards and pink sheets. They have opportunities do much better than the actual stock market investors in these companies, because you can negotiate contracts that let you cash out in their inevitable financing death spirals with very little risk to you.

You can do these things as an individual or as a holding company, but the holding company will limit your liability to the amount your holding company invested, instead of your personal assets, in case your financing starts to incur liability with the company.